# how can i add a background color to a layer kineticjs?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

How can I add a background color to a layer in kineticjs? I want to have multiple layers which have different background colors.

Something like:

```
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer({
                x: 0,
                y: 0,
                width : that.locationData.getCreativeLeftLoc(),
                height : that.locationData.getCreativeTopLoc(),
                background-color : 'black'
            });
```

Comment: I believe the property is "fill".

Comment: Or, actually, I don't believe the Layer object actually draws anything. It seems to serve only as a grouping object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. See the [docs](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Layer.html).

It goes `Node` > `Container` > `Layer`, none of which support drawing to themselves. They serve only to group other kinetic objects.